# Parse sort query via pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, parse-platform

I need to do a simple query sort with Parse.

I have two classes: `Captain` and `Boat`. Every `Captain` has a `Boat` pointer object.

I list all of the `Captain` objects in a table with their attributes, such as name, `Boat` name etc.

I need to be able to sort the query of `Captain` objects, via the `Boat` name. How can I?

I can sort a direct attribute with an `NSSortDescriptor` sort key such as the `Captain` `name`. But I need to sort the `Captain` objects by the `name` of their `Boat`.

Comment: Please describe why you are down voting, or I cannot make amends.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it would be helpful if you posted some code of what you've already tried and explained the specific problems with your current code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be nice if you could use dot notation on the sort qualifiers, like:

```
[captainQuery orderByAscending:@"boat.name"];
```

Unfortunately the attribute dot notation applies only to includeKey:.  So the way to do this to fetch, including the related object, then sort locally using the attribute of the related objects:

```
// ...
[captainQuery includeKey:@"boat"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *captains, NSError *error) {
    NSArray *sortedCaptains = [captains sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(PFObject *capA, PFObject *capB) {
        return [capA[@"boat"][@"name"] compare:capB[@"boat"][@"name"]];
        // or reverse param order for descending
    }];
}];
```

**EDIT** - @Logan helpfully points out that this answer doesn't scale well if your query pages through thousands of captains.  If the captain count is huge, it might be better to include a boat->captain pointer and do the following:

More roundabout-ly, you could fetch boats, orderByAscending on their name, includeKey their captains (if your boats have a back-pointer to captain), and then map over the returned (sorted) boats for their captains.

Comment: Works until too many objects.  You wouldn't want to fetch 10000+ objects when all you wanted was boat names starting with say, 'a'.  I think your back pointers suggestion is the most ideal.  You'd have to set up pointers two ways, but scales much better.

Comment: @Logan - not sure I agree.  Pulling multiple thousands of objects will be a problem whether or not you sort them locally.  My back-pointer idea would be a bad one, too if there were 10k boats.  I think we need to arrange our queries to return a reasonable count no matter what.  (parse enforces this with a max limit=1000)

Comment: Right, but by querying from the boats, couldn't you do paging?  Like query sorted by boatName w/ included key captain.  Then you could just get 100 at a time and page as necessary.  Otherwise you need to fetch all of the captain objects to ensure they're sorted accurately by boats.  Is that correct?

Comment: Right, I see your point.  The data should be designed to match the kind of queries you will do, and if you have 10k boats (a crazy-huge navy) and want to to this kind of query (or lookup a boat's captain), you probably better include a pointer that way. (edited)

Answer (score 0):

You can use relation query for multiple queries, the query code should looks like below:

```
PFObject *captain = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Captain"];
PFRelation *relation = [captain relationForKey:@"Boat"];
PFQuery *relQuery = [relation query];
[relQuery orderByDescending:@"name"];
// Add other query constraints

[relQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
       // There was an error
    } else {
       // All the captains sorted by related boat's names
    }
}];
```

There are some useful links below:

http://blog.parse.com/2012/05/17/new-many-to-many/
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-pointers/iOS

Answer (score 0):

There is a scalable solution for this, with rather minimal overhead:
Currently you have a table of boats and a table of captains, where each captain contains a pointer to a boat.

You should add a third table - let'c call it 'captains boats', which contains all the boats that are contained in a captain object. You maintain it by adding the boat when a new captain is added and by removing it from the table when a captain is deleted.

In order to sort the captains by their boats:

1. Query 'CaptainsBoats', sorted by whatever. Notice that even if this table contains a million records, you will get the first X that are relevant to you.
2. Query 'Captains', use the 'containedIn' method with the boat list from step 1: `[captainQuery whereKey:"boat" containedIn:boatList]`.
3. Now you have only the captain objects you need (out of a possible million). Sort them locally according to whatever.